# Clara_Medoids with large dataset of categorical data with many levels in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, similarity, categorical-data, large-data

I have a rather large dataset with purely categorical data.
Number of rows (samples) of data is over 30,000,000.
Attributes have been reduced to 4 (columns) and all of them (attributes) are categorical, with one of them having almost 50,000 levels!

I'm trying to cluster my data before further processing. However, due to the large size of data, it's not possible to use most clustering algorithms. 
I've chosen to use Clara_Medoids from ClusterR package to give the clustering a try. The problem i'm facing is that running the code gives me an error I cannot resolve.

Code:

```
Cmediods_5 <- ClusterR::Clara_Medoids(MyData, clusters = 5, samples = 3, sample_size = 0.0005, distance_metric = "simple_matching_coefficient")
```

and this is the error i receive:

> Error in check_NaN_Inf(data) : 
>     Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].

I have a feeling this error is due to the fact that i'm using the "simple_matching_coefficient" distance metric but I don't see any other viable option as my data is purely categorical.
Is there anyway to circumvent the data type issue to get this algorithm working properly? Obviously, i don't want to create any dummy variables, because as i explained earlier, one of the attributes has about 50,000 levels!

The options for Clara_Medoids function distance metrics are:
euclidean, manhattan, chebyshev, canberra, braycurtis, pearson_correlation, simple_matching_coefficient, minkowski, hamming, jaccard_coefficient, Rao_coefficient, mahalanobis

Unfortunately, it doesn't have gower distance, otherwise, that would have been my choice.

Comment: Work with a *sample* first, then scale up. Working with hugs data just to find out what does not work is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

The package vignette (http://mlampros.github.io/2016/09/12/clusterR_package/) has an example of this.

Using the `mushroom` data from the vignette an using the factor variables as is, results in the same error as you have:

```
library(ClusterR)


cl_f = Clara_Medoids(mushroom[-1], clusters = 2, distance_metric = 'hamming', 
  samples = 5, sample_size = 0.2, swap_phase = TRUE, verbose = F, threads = 1)

# Error in check_NaN_Inf(data) :
#   Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
```

The vignette suggests using the hamming distance (which counts the number of non matching variables) and converting the columns to numeric:

```
dta <- as.data.frame(lapply(mushroom[-1], as.integer))

cl_f = Clara_Medoids(dta, clusters = 2, distance_metric = 'hamming', 
  samples = 5, sample_size = 0.2, swap_phase = TRUE, verbose = F, threads = 1)
```

The vignette also gives an example using the gower distance, but this involves calculating the distance matrix, which is probably not an option with your dataset.

Comment: Thanks @Jan van der Laan, that's helpful. While I am not quite sure if Hamming dissimilarity measure is relevant to my data, I'll give that a try and see if I find the clusters pertinent based on this measure.

Comment: So thought to update that I tried Hamming distance and the clustering doesn't seem too pertinent unfortunately.

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira That's too bad. As Anony-Mousse suggested, try e.g. the gower distance using a sample of your data.   I suspect that will not help much. You only have 4 categorical variables. Comparison of two records will result in four 0/1's. Any distance measure will probably just be some weighted sum of the 1's.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation otherwise I would have added only a comment.

In my opinion giving a sample of your data would have helped solving your problem without making assumptions.

As @Jan van der Laan mentioned your data must be of type numeric (required for the distance matrix), which is not the case, that's why you get the error.

You should also know that the *simple_matching_coefficient* works only for binary data.

If your data consists only of categorical variables then the hamming distance is appropriate. The gower distance works well in case that the data is of mixed data type (numeric, factor etc.). Have a look also in the [gowdis function of the FD package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FD/FD.pdf) or in the [daisy function of the cluster package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cluster/cluster.pdf).

In the package description I've also added a [link](https://github.com/mlampros/ClusterR/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) in case anyone faces an issue.